# Xcode Sub-Project's Framework to be also included in Main Project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an `iOS` project with the following setup (running Xcode 5.1.1):

```
- MainProject.xodeproj
--- SubProject.xcodeproj
----- AThirdPartyFramework.framework
```

The `SubProject.xcodeproj` is linked to the `MainProject.xcodeproj` as a static library by including `SubProject.a` in *Build Phase 'Link Binary With Library'*.

The `AThirdPartyFramework.framework` is linked to `SubProject.xcodeproj` also in *Build Phase 'Link Binary With Library*.

`SubProject` imports headers from `AThirdPartyFramework.framework`. `MainProject` imports classes from `SubProject` but **never** from `AThirdPartyFramework.framework` directly; only indirectly through `SubProject`.

When building/testing `SubProject` targets, building succeeds without any errors. However, when attempting to build `MainProject` targets, I receive Compiler `Linker Errors`:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AThirdPartyFrameworkObject", referenced from: objc-class-ref in SubProject.a(MyClassThatReliesOnAThirdPartyFrameworkObject.o)

*Note: I'm not getting this error when building the `SubProject` Targets*

I'm able to get my `MainProject` to build by also linking the `AThirdPartyFramework.framework` to the `MainProject` (again using *Build Phase 'Link Binary With Library'*). However, that doesn't seem to compute in my head. Shouldn't my `SubProject.a` static library include `AThirdPartyFramework.framework` and expose to the `MainProject`?

Or is it a known limitation that `*.frameworks` need to be included in both SubProject and MainProject?

Comment: what kind of linker errors are you seeing?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, edited my question to show error

Comment: from that error, it looks to me like your ThirdPartyFramework is only building for the device and not for the simulator.  Check your architectures and valid architectures to be certain.

Comment: facing the same error with my project too..were you able to get a solution for this..

Comment: @smabbas ha thought only I had such a crazy project setup. I ended up adding the framework to both parent and child project and called it a day.. Not pretty, but working

Comment: @opfeffer i don't think its a crazy project set up .. :) should be a very common one..